# How can I generate a TileSet from an existing image of a level?

Tags: tilemap, godot, spritesheet, tilesets

Let say I have this level from *Zelda: ALTTP*.

I know that each tiles are 16x16. How can I generate a tileset and map from part of the original image?

[image]

<sup>([Image source](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/legendofzeldaalinktothepast/sheet/88873/))</sup>

Comment: When I [search "extract tileset from map"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=extract+tile-set+from+map&ia=web) I get [Online Tileset Extractor](http://cache.andre-michelle.com/tools/html/tileset-extractor.html) as the very first result. Is that suitable for your needs?

Comment: I hope you are only doing this for educational purposes and not because you want to violate the copyright of Nintendo by releasing a game which contains their intellectual property.

Comment: @Philipp Totally, I'm teaching computer science and I want to use known tileset with which the students can relate to.

Comment: @DMGregory wow! I've search on Google yesterday and haven't found anything. I guess my Google results are not the same as yours.

Comment: @NickB Correct, they aren't. Google learns from what you click on, and gives more of that. Even with search history erased and disabled. Even without a session open, since Google fingerprints your browser/device (which is how it can tell you when there was a login to your account from an unknown device). Try [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/).